# How to post status on Yammer using the rest api in ios?

Tags: ios, yammer

I am new to develop Yammer API in iOS to post some status.Can anyone please help by explaining how can I do that?
I [checked the url](https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json) which basically is used to post some text on yammer. I just need to know how do I do that?

```
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString: YAMMER_BASE_URL]; //YAMMER_BASE_URL = @"https://www.yammer.com" 

YMHTTPClient *client = [[YMHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL authToken:authToken]; 

NSDictionary *dict = @{@"body" : self.resultsTextView.text, @"broadcast":[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], @"group_id":@"83897" }; 

[client postPath:@"/api/v1/messages.json" parameters:dict 
success:^(id responseObject) { } 
failure:^(NSInteger statusCode, NSError *error) { }];
```

Comment: Please post you code?

Comment: NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString: YAMMER_BASE_URL];
YMHTTPClient *client = [[YMHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL authToken:authToken];
NSDictionary *dict =
        @{@"body" : self.resultsTextView.text,
          @"broadcast":[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
          @"group_id":@"83897"
          };
[client postPath:@"/api/v1/messages.json" parameters:dict success:^(id responseObject) {
        } failure:^(NSInteger statusCode, NSError *error) {

        }];

Comment: @MDMalik Can you please help me with the code? As I am getting this error all time:

Error Domain=com.alamofire.networking.error Code=-1011 "Expected status code in (200-299), got 400" UserInfo=0x7f95a3f89a50 {NSLocalizedDescription=Expected status code in (200-299), got 400, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json}

Comment: @SohamBhattacharjee Please post your code as an edit to your question so it's readable.

Comment: @rebello95 i have added my code, can you please help me with that ?

Comment: You are getting a 400 code in response. That means "bad request" [link](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E400.html) Maybe the message you are trying to send is empty?